# How to find URL "Outlook Web Access URL: " for Calendar overlay with Office 365 Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

I'm working on SharePoint online,In my site one calendar(Engineer calendar) which maintain all the events

But, I want display Office 365 calendar event in same calendar,for that overlay it's good option I think

[image: Calendar overlay]

but for I don't know where to find this URLs

**Outlook Web Access URL:**

**Exchange Web Service URL:**

**Update 1: Tried solution**

I have tried with this following Url please consider my company name armourcorporation
 1)

1. https://outlook.com/owa/ArmourCorporation
2. https://armourcorporation.sharepoint.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

for that getting me following error 
 *error: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match...* 
[image: Outlook calendar error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SharePoint Online Doesn't support Calendar overlay with Exchange web service**

[Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a) Microsoft mention on which version of SharePoint applies overlay. In that list "SharePoint Online" is not there.

I have talked with a Microsoft person to raise the issue in Office 365, and he also told me the same.

Comment: Jesus then why is there an option for it :(

Answer (score 2):

Click `Find` to automatically fill in web addresses for `Outlook Web Access URL` and `Exchange Web Service URL`.

[image]

If `Find` does not work in your environment, type the URLs manually as the following.

- **Outlook Web Access URL:** it should look like `https://outlook.com/owa/youcompany` or `https://outlook.com/<your domain>`that will redirect you to your `Outlook Web Access URL (owa)`
- **Exchange Web Service URL format :** `https://<ONLINE_URL>/EWS/Exchange.asmx`

If the above not help , contact your Exchange administrator for assistance.

Comment: I'm using office 365 so domain name is not available,but I tried with company name it's *digitalarmour* so my url is "https://outlook.com/owa/digitalarmour" but it getting error: *The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding * @M.Qassas

Comment: @amitKoyani main with domain name your online site url ? by the way Are you tried to add Outlook Web Access URL as the following https://outlook.com/owa/digitalarmour and exchange web service as https://<ONLINE_URL>/EWS/Exchange.asmx then Click OK and then click OK again. and check the result ? this https://outlook.com/owa/digitalarmour should be your outlook web access . also check https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kpalmvig/2011/09/15/easy-url-for-office-365-owa/

Comment: I have tried with this following Url please consider my company name **armourcorporation**
1) https://outlook.com/owa/ArmourCorporation
2) https://armourcorporation.sharepoint.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
*error: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match*
@M.Qassas

Comment: I have found some domain issue,Is it occurs this error
*error : You need to be a global admin to run the domain troubleshooter.*

Comment: Is it fare to exchange web service URL in office 365 mail or calendar? @M.Qassas

Comment: the exchange web service URL is the web service that will retrieve the login user calendar , once you provide the exchange web service URL , SharePoint knows the user who is logged in to the SharePoint Calendar page. With this information, SharePoint is able to contact the Exchange Web Service to retrieve the calendar data for that particular user only

Comment: when you get this error for that getting me following error error: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match... ?

Comment: For error I updated my question pls have alook@M.Qassas